# .htaccess file for redirecting directories of subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have looked at a few of the other .htaccess questions, but none have my specific usecase.

**SITUATION**

I have a website, say example.com. It has a sub-domain sub.example.com. The web host also provides a folder for every sub-domain: example.com/sub

I want to link both the sub.example.com and example.com/sub to othersite.com/some/folder/path/

What I have so far (the code also adds www things, don't ask why, unless it can fix things):

in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /

##Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

##301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /sub/(.*) https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/$1
```

in /sub/.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /sub/

##Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sub.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

##301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/$1
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When I use `sub.example.com/foo/bar` the redirect works (it redirects to `https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/foo/bar`)

When I use `example.com/sub` it breaks (it redirects to `https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/sub/foo/bar`, notice the ../**sub**/..)

What do I need to change to make it work so that the sub folder isn't added to the path?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rules in `mod_rewrite`. Keep your `/sub/.htaccess` as

```
##Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /sub/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sub.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

##301 Redirect Entire Directory
RewriteRule (.*) https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Test this after clearing browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that mod_dir does because you're accessing a directory *without the trailing slash*. By default accessing a directory without a trailing slash gets the request flagged for a redirect to the same directory *with the trailing slash*. This often messes rewrites or other redirects. Try turning it off and adding an additional redirect to handle the trailing slash:

```
RewriteBase /

DirectorySlash Off

##Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

##301 Redirect deviantart Directory
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*) https://othersite.com/some/folder/path/$1 [L,R=301]
```